# disable dynamic id buttons with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using VB.Net, MVC 5, razor and jQuery.  I have a razor view that creates buttons I'm trying to disable on the user click.  I generally accomplish this task using jQuery:

```
$('#id').prop("disabled", true);
```

My task is new to me in that my buttons are generated like this:

```
@For i As Integer = 0 To Model.hrmnValues.Count - 1
    @<div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="#" id="@Model.inventoryCategoryAttIDs(i)" 
           onclick="acceptChange('@Model.hrmnValues(i)',
              @Model.inventoryCategoryAttIDs(i), @Model.uniqueItemID)">Accept Change</a>
    </div>      
Next
```

My `onClick` function is similar to this:

```
function acceptChange(newValue, categoryAttID, itemID) {
    $('#categoryAttID').prop("disabled", true);
}
```

This obviously does not work, as it is looking for an `id` with the name of categoryAttID.  I have also tried putting the categoryAttID into it's own variable like this:

```
var idToDisable = "#" + categoryAttID;
```

and then putting `idToDisable` into the jQuery call to disable the button, this did not work.

Given this situation how can I disable the button that is clicked?

There will be multiple buttons on this page making use of the function, the function actually performs an ajax call.  The idea is to limit the user to performing one ajax call per button.

The html is rendered like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <font>First Name</font>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <font>John</font>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <font>No Record Found</font>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="#" id="2" 
                   onclick="acceptChange('CHRISTOPHER', 2, 0)">Accept Change</a>
    </div>
</div>        
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <font>Last Name</font>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <font>MURRAY</font>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <font>No Record Found</font>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="#" id="3" 
                   onclick="acceptChange('MURRAY', 3, 0)">Accept Change</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you post the resulting html?

Comment: Looks like you are disabling the element that ws clicked. Easiest thing then would be `$(this).prop(disable, true)`

Comment: @Andrei that didn't work

Comment: @rogerdeuce, well, i did make a mistake, should be `$(this).prop("disabled", true)`

Comment: That's the way I tried it. No errors in the console and goes on about it's merry way through the rest of the function, but it doesn't disable the button.  @Andrei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already passing the button's `id` to your function as the second argument -

> acceptChange('@Model.hrmnValues(i)',@Model.inventoryCategoryAttIDs(i), @Model.uniqueItemID)

So you can change your function to -

```
function acceptChange(newValue, categoryAttID, itemID) {
  $('#' + categoryAttID).prop("disabled", true);
}
```

Also, there isn't a disabled property available for links (see - [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)) if you want to disable your elements on click try using a button instead.

Since you appear to be using bootstrap after changing your links to buttons you might want to change your function to -

```
function acceptChange(newValue, categoryAttID, itemID) {
  $('#' + categoryAttID).prop("disabled", true);
  $('#' + categoryAttID).addClass("disabled");
}
```

Comment: I added a list of category names to my view model.  I'm using these names for the ids and as an added parameter.  This is still not disabling the button on click, although it throws no error.  It now reads `id = FirstName` and alerting the variable + # yields `#FirstName`

Comment: @rogerdeuce sorry, I should have looked at your question a little more closely, links cannot be disabled (see - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) if you want to disable on click try using a button instead (or converting your link to a jQuery-UI button - http://api.jqueryui.com/button/ and disabling that)

Comment: html5 allows numeric id's, spec quoted is outdated. Answer is incorrect in that regard

Comment: Got there eventually.  I had already changed the id to be a string, so I left that in.  Concatenated the # onto the variable, then used `$(idToDisable).hide();`